# Analytical method for solving "continuous difference equations" and/or integral equations

Tags: calculus, integral-equations

I'm trying to find a function, $G(t)$, that satisfies the relation

$$G(t+1) - G(t) = f(t)$$

for some known function, $f(t)$, for $t \in R$. I have been able to come up with solutions for a few instances of $f(t)$ by trial and error and inspection, namely:

$$\begin{align}
f(t) & = m t + f_0 & & => & & G(t) = (m/2) t^2 + (f_0 - m/2) t
\\
f(t) & = f_0 (1 + r)^t & & => & & G(t) = (f_0 / r) (1 + r)^t
\end{align}$$

where $f_0$, $r$, and $m$ are constants. But I can't seem to identify any method which can be applied generally.

I'm having a tough time even naming the class of problem - I wrote "continuous difference equation," though that doesn't seem to be a commonly used term. My current thinking is that I might be able to write this as an integral equation in some way, since the $G(t+1) - G(t)$ is reminiscent of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and the solutions I've found so far are kind of similar to the integrals of $f(t)$, though just a bit off. If anyone has seen anything like this before or knows even what to call this type of problem it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly the subject of what is called [Indefinite Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum)
$$
\Delta G(t) = G(t + 1) - G(t) = f(t)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad G(t) = \Delta ^{\, - 1} f(t) = \sum\nolimits_{\,t} {f(t)} 
$$
that is to find the function $G(t)$ whose finite difference is a given function $f(t)$.

The topic has many similarities with the (definite / indefinite) integrals, and the solution methods are much alike:
 - basic theory and identities;
 - table of basic integrals;
 - lot of expertise and intuition to put up a chain combining the above.

Comment: The two solutions that I included in the original question can be almost trivially computed using the tables provided in the link you posted.

Comment: @mhuneau : in fact , but same as for integrals, do not forget to add a constant to the indefinite sum (which actually, apart from a constant , can more generally be a a periodic function of period 1).

Comment: For my application I'm only interested in computing things like $G(t_2) - G(t_1)$,  which I believe means that I can safely ignore any constant terms, since they'll always cancel out. When $t_2 - t_1 \ne 1$ then presumably the result would still be affected by any periodic components. I'll have to try a few examples to see what they look like. Maybe I'll need to formulate some additional conditions.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is through the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform). This gives for your equation
$$
(e^{-s}-1)G(s)=f(s),
$$
that is
$$
G(s)=\frac{f(s)}{e^{-s}-1}.
$$
This yields the solution
$$
G(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{T\to\infty}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}e^{st}\frac{f(s)}{e^{-s}-1}\,ds
$$
where the integral should be performed as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform).

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with Laplace Transforms... Are they still applicable when $t \in R$, as opposed to just $t>0$? I'm also having trouble finding the rule for the Laplace transform of  $G(t+1)$ - do you have a source for that?

Comment: You can check at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Laplace_transforms. A time shift corresponds to an exponential in $s$. A bilateral Laplace transform also exists, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Bilateral_Laplace_transform.